# Serial downvoting not caught by script:

Tags: support

Serial downvoting not caught by script:

-4  today

-2  13 hours ago    downvote    Does Go support operator type variables?

-2  14 hours ago    downvote    Why are Lists used infrequently in GoLang:

-6  yesterday
    23:35   downvote    Do short variable declarations lead to poorly structured code in Go?

-2  23:39   downvote    Initialising multiple structs in go

-2  23:28   downvote    How to disable Golang unused import error

-2  19:43   downvote    Is it possible to retreive a column value by name 
using GoLang database/sql

Comment: It's been reversed now. Check your SO profile.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you feel you are being targeted by serial downvoting which is not being detected due to gaming the system, then raise a custom flag on one of the posts with the downvote and explain the situation. Make sure to let the system have a chance at catching it automatically though, the script tends to run at the beginning of the UTC day (but waiting 24 hours in general is a good idea).

Explain that you *think* you are being downvoted by one user over a span of multiple posts and then link all of them. Do not state explicitly that you know who it is or that you know for a fact it is serial downvoting because it is impossible to know for certain, so this may negatively affect the flag results.

Keep a neutral tone, I guarantee the mod reading the flag had nothing to do with it. They have ways of figuring these things out though.

Comment: Maybe also to say here: I would wait one day to see if the system detects it!

Comment: @Rizier123 - I thought the assumption was that if it came to this, the script had already had a chance to run since the OP states "not caught by script".

Comment: My understanding was that the process runs overnight, so I waited until that could happen. Perhaps I didn't wait long enough.