# Is it a wrong thing to vote for close VLQ code-request with two images? Getting revenge downvotes

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, moderation

There was one question which had two images and the user wants to do that implementation. There is no code, no attempt, no research. He was asking us to write a code for him for that two images. I downvoted the question and vote for close. As it is off-topic here.

As I downvoted and voted for close the user started rude and abusive comments. Now he had started to downvote my answers daily around 3 4 answers.

[image]

I want to ask the community that is I am doing anything wrong. Should I need to write code for him?

In which situations I should  vote for close?

And of course what about my reputation points. I want to report this user if someone can help!

Comment: Nope, carry on DV and VTC-ing questions that warrant it

Comment: I think this is not fair at all. this type of user's account should be reported and need to take some action.

Comment: Im sure theres probably a duplicate question for this but I couldn't find it... you can flag one of your own posts that you think has been targetted explaining what you think is going on for a moderator to look into it

Comment: If you see rude/abusive comments: flag them! If you suspect voting fraud/ targeted downvotes: mod flag! (and include all the relevant info)

Comment: This may help you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291368

Comment: @S.L.Barth it is not duplicate and if you want to close then close this question but before that i want justice from moderators

Comment: Ok I will try to flag and call moderator as you all said.. thank you everyone :)

Comment: @VishvaDave Good luck! You have my sympathy; those vengenance downvoters are just jerks.

Comment: @S.L.Barth this is not just the question for downvotes or some 10 15 reputations.. but this way is wrong..If stackoverflow is giving us rights for close then should have some system for us too. As we are not doing anything wrong :(

Comment: @VishvaDave This is why I don't comment anymore... it helps to stay anonymous

Comment: @NickA You are right i will take care of it next time

Comment: @VishvaDave the same this happing with me yesterday i have closed this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507394/just-asking-how-can-i-achieve-this-functionality-use-with-bottom-navigation and that user has down voted in my some answer you check that i think its same user down voting your, my and Rohit5k2   in  answer

Comment: Yes may be same user. but he had deleted the question

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I think voting-to-close this meta question into [A downvote a day keeps the reversal-script away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308502/a-downvote-a-day-keeps-the-reversal-script-away) is way too cryptic, that's not even a question and it merely inquires whether OP should care about a stealth revenge downvoter. This question however is asking if the VtC itself was correct.

Comment: I retitled that [Stealth revenge-downvoter: a downvote a day keeps the reversal-script away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308502/stealth-revenge-downvoter-a-downvote-a-day-keeps-the-reversal-script-away), but it's still not a dupe of this, and it's not articulating a question. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: I retitled this *"Is it a wrong thing to vote for close VLQ code-request with two images? Getting revenge downvotes"* to articulate your subquestions, which are already covered on Meta. No you're not wrong. Opinions will always differ on whether to leave a comment when you VtC, whether that risks exposing you to revenge-downvotes. In this case it's fairly harmless since they will fairly quickly run out of rep, or get busted by the serial-downvote script.

Comment: @NileshRathod at least the behavior is consistent. Yvette got their down votes as well probably for being the delete voter there.

Comment: @rene yup you are right

Comment: @NickA But it's reversed anyway... why does it matter?

Comment: @user202729 It's reversed in case where the users doing it aren't aware that revenge voting/voting rings/targeting users etc. aren't allowed, because they may well downvote a dozen posts, it's more dangerous if they systematically downvote 1/2 posts per day, and frankly I'd rather not have to go through the rigmarole of researching it, compiling evidence and making a mod flag. That and because I have no reason to explain my reasoning for downvotes/close votes

Comment: These votes and the ones they targeted at others have been invalidated. We had previously warned them about being abusive to others, and they used that opportunity to start serially downvoting moderators as well, so that didn't exactly end well for them. Thanks for the flags.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I want to ask the community that is I am doing anything wrong.

No, you are doing your job as expected, carry on using your rights of VTC-ing.

> Should I need to write code for him?

No, Stackoverflow is not free coding service. We help on some specific problem, but it's the user's responsibility to put some efforts from his side. The SO users are not here to do some home work of other users.

> In which situations I should  vote for close?

If you found any question as **off-topic** or question asking for **Can you write some code for me?** or question asking for  **Please write demo code**  or **question with zero efforts**  this type of questions deserve a close vote.

Please check the below links. You will get the idea in which situations you should  vote for close.

[Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions)

[How to flag/close as "not a code-writing service"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348591/how-to-flag-close-as-not-a-code-writing-service)

> I want to report this user

Check this:

[How can I report a specific bad user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66444/how-can-i-report-a-specific-bad-user)

[What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

> And of course what about my reputation points

Check this:

[What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: _"Can you write some code for me? or question asking for Please write demo code or question with zero efforts this type of questions deserve a close vote."_ the top answer (which is from a community manager) to your first linked question directly negates what you're saying there.

Answer (score 16):

You should flag all rude/abusive comments.

If you suspect revenge down-votes, you should take one of your own down-voted posts then flag it for diamond moderator attention. Explain that you suspect revenge serial down-voting.

Looking at your account, I definitely agree that revenge down-voting is what's happening. Notably, after tossing out 3 revenge down-votes against the same user, there's some automatic protection against revenge down-voting kicking in. That's why you only get 3 votes at a time.

When this automatic revenge-vote detection kicks in, I believe moderators will be notified and can take actions. I don't know the exact mechanics for this, there's a lot of things going on behind the scenes that we normal users don't see. This kind of behavior typically ends with a ban and a rep-reversal.

---

But please note that there's always two sides here. While this user's behavior isn't acceptable and needs to be addressed by a moderator, please also consider how to respond in comments more carefully.

I would not recommend using http://idownvotedbecau.se, dropping a single line comment with that link tends to come across as hostile rather than helpful. It is probably just a matter of time before SO bans that URL like they have done with lmgtfy.com. If you wish to help the OP, post a link to the official SO help instead.

Otherwise just downvote, close vote and move on. There's usually no way to help these kind of people anyway - they don't want to improve, they just want to put as little effort as possible into solving their problem.

Comment: the bit about "idownvotedbecau.se" is true, but it's too bad because the text behind those "snarky" links is really good.

Comment: Yes, you are right... I made a mistake too I added this link... Maybe it gets user angry... I will take care of this in future Thank you!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Easily solved by just linking to the help center instead, if you're dead set on just posting a link rather than commenting on what needs to be fixed.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355950/is-idownvotedbecau-se-recommended/355995#355995